# Using an @Autowired resource with "try with resource"

Tags: java, spring

Given the following:

```
public class ResourceOne implements AutoCloseable {...}
```

with an instance of `ResourceOne` instantiated in (Spring) XML config.

How should this object (when autowired) be used with the "try-with-resources Statement", since you are required to instantiate the resource in the try block?

One approach could be to use a reference (see below), but this isn't really optimal.

```
public class Test {
@Autowired
ResourceOne test;
//...
public void execute()
{
 //...
 try (ResourceOne localTest = test)
 {
   localTest.init()
   localTest.readLine();
   //...
 }
}
```

Comment: what do you wnat to achieve with  try `(ResourceOne localTest = test)`

Comment: It's a workaround to have `test` closed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK I think the approach that you have taken seems to be the only way.

```
try (ResourceOne localTest = test)
 {
   localTest.init()
   localTest.readLine();
   //...
 }
```

I am assuming that you have your autowired resource declared with prototype scope though right.

```
    @Bean
    @Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
    public Resource1 resource1() {
        return new Resource1();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to autowire the spring application context and have it retrieve an instance of the bean at runtime.

```
public class Test {

@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext

//...
public void execute()
{
 //...
 try (ResourceOne localTest = applicationContext.getBean(ResourceOne.class))
 {
   localTest.init()
   localTest.readLine();
   //...
 }
}
```

This way you don't risk having a non-functional instance of ResourceOne in your code that could potentially be used again from another method and result in an exception because is't already been closed.

Comment: But mocking in unit test will be very disappointing in this scenario I think?